# How to merge a overlapping points into a single feature to reduce Map "noise"

Tags: qgis, point, merge, clustering, combine

I have a shapefile of the locations of wind turbines within the central flyway. I was attempting to show the size by the total number of turbines however I am having a problem with many large scale farms being close to each other and it's taking away from the message. I was wondering if there was a way to merge points within a certain distance so that instead of have 9 separate points I could have one large point? I have inserted the image below. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using a heat map style?  It'll remove all the points and show areas of highly clustered turbines.  It can also be based on the attribute of the number of turbines at each site rather than their proximity to each other (as long as you have that number in the attribute table).

In the style properties of the point layer change the style from 'Single symbol'/'Categorized' (whatever you're using in your image) to 'Heat Map'.

Set the 'Weight points by' to the attribute that has the turbine numbers for each site.

See what it looks like then play around with the radius property to get a good spread of the heatmap.  Also changing the 'Layer blending mode' to *Overlay* or *multiply* will let you see the basemap beneath more clearly than just changing the layers transparency.

Comment: +1 I asked a clarification about the real needs of the OP, but I was pointing to the same solution!

Comment: It was either this or point clustering but I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish that in qgis

Comment: Hey everyone! thanks for the quick answers! So I was attempt to do more of a tolerance distance. I did the Kernal density and the point density and they are not really reflecting what my data is showing me. I did a hot spot analysis, which I like because it is showing me the areas of higher impact. I am not sure how to select the weight point by? Am I creating the heat map incorrectly?

Comment: Could you ask this as a separate question, including another image with your heat map and what the attribute table looks like of your turbine layer

Comment: yes of course! I can do that if that would help